# For loop isn't printing existing common values between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

So I have two datasets, drinks and drinks2, about the nutritional information of drinks at Starbucks, each one having a different set of drinks as observations.

Columns of drinks:

```
['Beverage', 'Calories', 'Fat (g)', 'Carb. (g)', 'Fiber (g)','Protein (g)', 'Sodium (g)']
```

Columns of drinks2:

```
['Beverage_category', 'Beverage', 'Beverage_prep', 'Calories', 'Fat (g)','Trans Fat (g)', 'Saturated Fat (g)', 'Sodium (g)', 'Carb. (g)', 'Cholesterol (mg)', 'Fiber (g)', 'Sugars (g)', 'Protein (g)','Vitamin A (% DV)', 'Vitamin C (% DV)', 'Calcium (% DV)', 'Iron (% DV)', 'Caffeine (mg)']
```

Upon merging the two datasets together on their common `'Beverage'` column, the new dataset's `'Beverage'` column consists of multiple occurrences of three values; Caffe Latte, Caramel Macchiato, Cappuccino, which signifies the presence of these values in both of the original 'Beverage' columns in the initial dataframes, and their presence is confirmed upon manual checking.

However, when trying to print out the common values using the following for loop:

```
for i, v in drinks2['Beverage'].iteritems():
    if v in drinks['Beverage']:
        print(v)
```

Nothing is shown on the output. There are common values between the two beverage columns and yet nothing is printed. Any idea why?

Comment: What if you print the values of i and v in each iteration ?

Comment: Do you have a sample of dfs?

Comment: you don't compare same data types. notice that you do: for i,v in dict1.iteritems() and then compare it to v in dict(). you shall either compare dict1().iteritems() with dict2.iteritems() or dict1.values() with dict2.values().

Answer (score 0):

to get a column with common values

```
import pandas as pd


d1 = {'Beverage': ['Beverage', 'Calories', 'Fat (g)', 'Carb. (g)', 'Fiber (g)','Protein (g)', 'Sodium (g)',]}
d2 = {'Beverage': ['Beverage_category', 'Beverage', 'Beverage_prep', 'Calories', 'Fat (g)','Trans Fat (g)',
      'Saturated Fat (g)', 'Sodium (g)', 'Carb. (g)', 'Cholesterol (mg)', 'Fiber (g)',
      'Sugars (g)', 'Protein (g)','Vitamin A (% DV)', 'Vitamin C (% DV)', 'Calcium (% DV)',
      'Iron (% DV)', 'Caffeine (mg)',]}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)


dx = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Beverage', how='inner')
```

to make your code working

```
print([i for i in sum(d1.values(),[]) if i in sum(d2.values(), [])])
```

Answer (score 0):

To find common elements, you can use instead:

```
import numpy as np    
np.intersect1d(drinks['Beverage'], drinks2['Beverage'])
```

If you want to make your code works, you could use this:

```
 for v in drinks2['Beverage']:
    if v in drinks['Beverage'].values:
        print(v)
```

Or:

```
for i, v in drinks2['Beverage'].iteritems():
    for j, w in drinks['Beverage'].iteritems():
        if v == w:
            print(v)
```

Or:

```
for v in drinks2['Beverage']:
    for w in drinks['Beverage']:
        if v == w:
            print(v)
```

Comment: this gave me the desired result! However, still wondering as to why my original code didn't work theoretically

Comment: I added the part to show how your code would work, check it :)

Comment: @TheFutureNav You can easily add `.values`: `if v in drinks['Beverage'].values`

Comment: You are welcome :) if the answer solved your problem, please consider to accept it https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work